# NodeJS C++ native module: Create designated thread pool

Tags: c++, node.js, threadpool, native, libuv

for a application I am currently developing, I need to start instances of a shared library in parallel.

As I want to have fine-grained control over the amount of parallel instances (-license of library restricts amount of parallelism to a fixed amount of threads), I am wondering if there's a easy way to create&maintain a own thread pool in the native module?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Basically we must set the UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE environment variable before the thread pool is created.

This can be done in three ways:

1. Putting this line in your .bashrc file will affect all the opened node processes under that user

   ```
   export UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE=10
   ```
2. Set it before the process is open

   ```
   UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE=10 node myscript.js
   ```
3. Set it inside the javascript, in the first line:

   ```
   process.env.UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE = 10;
   ```